# Как грамотно работать с деструкторами классов в Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Общеизвестно, что после работы с файловым потоком его надо освободить, чтобы очистить память и, что не менее важно, снять блокировку с файла. Но тут возникает вопрос: Что, если мы работаем с файлом внутри функции?

Теоретически, после завершения работы подпрограммы, вся выделенная под неё память должна быть очищена сама, то есть мы делаем лишнюю работу. Более того, в некоторых случаях попытка запустить деструктор вообще вызывает исключение.

Как определить, когда следует применить деструктор, а когда нет и что следует предусмотреть при написании деструктора пользовательского класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Что, если мы работаем с файлом внутри функции?***

Значит нужно освобождать объекты только тогда, когда они уже никому не понадобятся.

***Теоретически, после завершения работы подпрограммы, вся выделенная под неё память должна быть очищена сама, то есть мы делаем лишнюю работу.***

Теоретически система должна освободить ресурсы выделенные программе, после её завершения. Однако, существуют такие ресурсы, которые могут быть освобождены только при перезагрузке системы, если программа не освободила их корректно при выходе. Более того, освобождение ресурсов - это не *лишняя работа*, поскольку ресурсы не бесконечные и, если программа работает продолжительное время, они таки закончатся.

***Более того, в некоторых случаях попытка запустить деструктор вообще вызывает исключение.***

Это чаще всего происходит при попытке вызвать деструктор у уже освобождённого объекта, поскольку ссылка на него по прежнему указывает в какую-то область памяти, которая может быть уже занята чем угодно.

***Как определить, когда следует применить деструктор, а когда нет и что следует предусмотреть при написании деструктора пользовательского класса?***

Если в пользовательском классе используются только простые типы (числа, строки, записи (record) и т.д.), то деструктор такому классу не нужен. В большинстве случае деструктор нужен только, если в классе вызываются методы `Create` других классов. Однако, это не освобождает от необходимости вызывать деструктор объектов вашего класса! Все классы наследуются от `TObject` или его наследников, даже если это явно не указано. При вызове конструктора класса вызываются также конструкторы всех его предков. Таким образом, при вызове деструктора *объекта пользовательского класса* (наследника `TObject`), если в этом классе деструктор не определён, будет вызван деструктор `TObject`, который освободит ресурсы веделенные конструктором класса `TObject`.